# How to select and merge verticies into separate triangles?

Tags: animation

For my blender model, I have an image of a half-sphere. On its face it is triangulated and I want to merge the triangles together so they are like the portion that the red arrow is pointing to.
[image]

What I have tried doing is first going to select on the bottom left, and then using circle select. I selected the areas and I tried doing many different things :

First, I tried pressing Alt M and I was given the choice of merging at center, at cursor, or collapse. None of these can give the function I need.

Then, I tried pressing Connect (Select -> Vertices -> Connect (c)) and nothing happened.

I have tried using this: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Vertices/

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: alt-J will give you quads...